# How to draw an SVG Q Operation?

Tags: android, svg

How to add an svg's 'Q' operation to an android path ?

sample:

I draw a 'C' operation like this

```
m 2846.8731,1484.2144 c 0,0.9961 -0.8268,1.6342 -0.8203,0.638

path.cubicTo (0,0.9961, -0.8268,1.6342, -0.8203,0.638);
```

Now how to draw a 'Q' operation ?

```
m 2846.8731,1484.2144 q 0,0.9961 -0.8268,1.6342 -0.8203,0.638 -2.2461,0.638

path.????????(0,0.9961, -0.8268,1.6342);
```

Comment: Use [path.quadTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path#quadTo(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)), obviously

Comment: I get bad results, but I'll try again.